# Unbounded Solution for 2nd Order PDE.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $\Omega=(a,b)\times\mathbb{R}^+$ and that $\phi:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi=\phi(x,t)$ satisfies
\begin{equation} L(\phi)=0,\;\;\;\;\;(1) \end{equation}
where $L$ is a 2nd order differential operator *in the first variable $x$ only*. Furthermore, suppose that $$\phi(a,t)=\phi(b,t)=f(t),\;\;\text{ for all }t\in\mathbb{R}^+.$$
If $f$ is bounded, can there be a differential operator $L$ and a function $\phi\in\ker L$ such that $|\phi|$ is unbounded? What if $f$ is unbounded?

**Note 1**: The function $\phi$ is in $H^2\left((a,b\right))$ for all $t$ and $C(\mathbb{R}^+)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ but these conditions can be changed for the sake of an example/counter-example.

**Note 2**: Of course, a suitable choice $\phi_0(x)=\phi(x,0)$ is to be given also as part of the problem.

**My try**: Suppose that we take $f\equiv 0$. If $\phi(x,t)$ is a solution for
(1), I claim that $t\cdot\phi(x,t)$ is also a solution for (1).

Comment: What are the coefficients of $L$ like? Are they constant or non constant?

Comment: there is no restriction on $L$ except what is provided above.

Comment: If $f$ is unbounded then $|\phi|$ is unbounded too, due to the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose a following counterexample. Let $a=0$, $b=\pi$, and $f\equiv 0$. For any function $g:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R$, a function $\phi:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ such that $\phi(x,t)=g(t)\sin x$ for each $(x,t)\in\Omega$, satisfies the boundary condition. If the function $g$ is unbounded then the function $\phi$ is unbounded too. If $L=\tfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+1$ then $L(\phi)=0$.